# XCUI tests failed due to Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 30 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations

Tags: xcode8, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane, xcuitest

```
 let webViewsQuery = app.webViews
    let emailOrPhoneTextField = webViewsQuery/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.textFields["Email or phone"]/*[[".otherElements[\"Sign in – Google accounts\"].textFields[\"Email or phone\"]",".textFields[\"Email or phone\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == TextField")
    expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: emailOrPhoneTextField, handler: nil)
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 30, handler: nil)
    emailOrPhoneTextField.tap()
```

> Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 30 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Expect predicate `exists == 1` for object "Email or phone" TextField" when running through fastlane scan

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've never fulfilled your expectation (with `expectation.fulfill()` method). Use `XCTWaiter` if you don't care about expectation fulfilment.

Comment: expectation(for predicate:...) doesn't require .fulfill to be called - it's a special-case expectation which evaluates itself repeatedly when waitForExpectations is called, based on the outcome of the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not just that you need to make your expectation evaluate to true?

```
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
```

or

```
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
```